# Where to find the System.management dll

Tags: clrstoredprocedure, system.management

I am trying to build an SQL CLR stored procedure that references an IBM WebSphere MQ dll. I'm having problems doing this on my work machine, so I decided to see if I could just get this to work on my home comp using localhost. I've made progress in getting a different error, however I'm not sure where the system.management dll is located...

Here is a copy of the error message:

Msg 10301, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Assembly 'amqmdnet' references assembly 'system.management, version=2.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.', which is not present in the current database. SQL Server attempted to locate and automatically load the referenced assembly from the same location where referring assembly came from, but that operation has failed (reason: 2(The system cannot find the file specified.)). Please load the referenced assembly into the current database and retry your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is installed in GAC, Check the version of .Net that you have it on your system

Answer (score 1):

You must register this assembly in SQL Server

```
create assembly [System.Management]
from 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Management.dll'
with permission_set = unsafe
```